# Oracle : IN and OR

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements

I've a scenrio which process many data in Oracle database. In some cases, the variable `Sec_email` will contain many values and in some cases `Sec_email` will contain `null` or `' '`.
so can please any one tell me how to write a query for this?

I tried with

```
(C.SECONDARY_EMAIL IN ('?,?') OR '' = '' )
```

where C is the Client table.

When I use this i get the count as 0.

Comment: `OR '' = ''` is true for all the records.

Comment: @Raja Anbazhagan: Actually, in Oracle `''` is the same as `null`, so `'' = ''` is always false.

Comment: in that case is the `OR '' = '' ` necessary?

Comment: You mention that in some cases sec_email will contain *many values*. What do you mean with *many values*? is that an array or a string with comma separated?

Comment: UNKOWN. `'' = ''` is same, on Oracle, as `NULL = NULL` which has the truth value **UNKOWN**. (Which matters if you take the negation, but not in this context.)

Comment: @RubahMalam its an array of values

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a not null check before the `IN` comparison like

```
Sec_email is not null and C.SECONDARY_EMAIL IN (...
```

Answer (score 1):

One obvious problem is that Oracle (by default) treats empty strings as `NULL`.  So:  `'' = ''` is the same as `NULL = NULL`, which is never true.

Arrgh.

In any case, you are probably constructing the query, so use `is null` instead:

```
(C.SECONDARY_EMAIL IN ('?,?') OR '' IS NULL
```

I think the real problem, though, is the first comparison.  The `IN` list has one element with a constant, not two (but perhaps that is your intention).  If you want to put a variable number of values for comparison, one method uses regular expressions.  For instance:

```
C.SECONDARY_EMAIL REGEXP_LIKE '^val1|val2|val3$' or '' IS NULL
```

Comment: Did you mean to use the regex like function? The `like` operator doesn't do regexes.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance . . . Yes, that was very much my intention.  I don't know why my fingers didn't type it.

Comment: When i use this I don't get the complete data.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get a list of values when some of them is null you should use:

```
("some other conditions" OR C.SECONDARY_EMAIL IS NULL)
```

The question is if it is not null and not `' '` value what you are expecting, if it should be some king of
 pattern you should use regular expression:

```
regexp_like(C.SECONDARY_EMAIL, '^(.+?[,]+?)+$')
```

Also, if you have a few conditions in where clause use should use brackets to group you conditions null check and another one.

All conditions i this case will be divided by `OR`.

```
(C.SECONDARY_EMAIL IS NULL OR regexp_like(C.SECONDARY_EMAIL, '^(.+?[,]+?)+$'))
```

or

```
(C.SECONDARY_EMAIL IS NULL OR  regexp_like(C.SECONDARY_EMAIL, '^(.+?[,]+?)+$')
 OR C.SECONDARY_EMAIL = ' ')
```

Comment: I am not getting the complete data.

Comment: Then you should choose regex which will suit your conditions. Describe values you would like to get if it is not null nor

Comment: It always takes the `OR` condition. when `IS NULL` condition is not considered.

Comment: Now I'm trying with `AND (c.SECONDARY_EMAIL IN ('') OR c.SECONDARY_EMAIL IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: total records are around 19+ and in '1043022' value there's only 2. when i pass values like `C.SECONDARY_EMAIL IN '1043022'` i get result as 19+

Comment: Yes, that is right, you have to use AND (c.SECONDARY_EMAIL IN ('') OR c.SECONDARY_EMAIL IS NOT NULL) if you have some other condition OR should be used only inside brackets.

Comment: I'm not getting. Whatever i do `IN` condition is not executing.

Comment: IN works following way - it takes value and try to check whether it's in IN list. For example some_field in (1, 2, 5) or another example some_field in ('first', 'second', 'third') it will compare whether some_field equals 'first' or 'second' or 'third'.

Comment: or is there any way I can skip this line if it is null?

Comment: Yes, like this AND (C.SECONDARY_EMAIL IN ('email1', 'email2') OR C.SECONDARY_EMAIL IS NULL ) - will work following - find all who's  C.SECONDARY_EMAIL equals 'email1' or 'email2' or field C.SECONDARY_EMAIL IS NULL.

Comment: Can you send a whole SELECT with the schema and data you want select.

Comment: Its a very big query. I'm actually accessing from more than 15 tables. Can I use `NVL` or `DECODE` function?

Comment: "Can I use NVL or DECODE function?" - Yes, you can. If it is too big to post it heare use http://sqlfiddle.com/.